# C++ expected unqualified id

Tags: c++

On line five of my code, the compiler raises an error. "error: expected unqualified-id
`std::string send(message); {`"

What error is this? How do I fix it?

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
std::string message = "blank";
std::string send(message); { // here it raises the error
        std::ofstream MyFile("messagepy.txt");
        std::ofstream MyFile; << "Files can be tricky, but it is fun enough!";
        }
// // // // // // // // // // // // // //
int main() {
    std::cout << "defining is done.";
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't put a semicolon there. Edit : I thought it was just a typo, but there are a ton of errors in this code. You can't effectively learn C++ by trial and error.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? There is a lot of syntactical errors and it's hard to understand what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Stop putting semicolons everywheree

Answer (score 2):

You have some syntax errors in there. Not sure what your code is meant to do, but here is my guess:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


void send(std::string message)
{
    std::ofstream MyFile("messagepy.txt");
    MyFile << message;
    MyFile << "Files can be tricky, but it is fun enough!";
}

int main()
{
    std::string message = "blank";
    send(message);
    std::cout << "defining is done." << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the error is caused because you didn't `#include <string>`.

But there are other problems too. It sort of looks like you meant to create a `send` function but the semicolon `;` is causing it to look like a declaration of a global variable `send` constructed with `message`, and then a code block which is a syntax error because it isn't part of a function.

Comment: `<iostream>` includes `<string>` with some compilers/standard library, so it is probably not the OP issue. (even if adding proper header would be correct/portable).

Comment: @Jarod42 No, it doesn't. It sometimes includes string forwarding headers with incomplete implementations which makes people *think* it is working, but then they get incredibly confusing template errors.

It all depends on the library in use and even the version of the library.

Comment: @Jarod42 OK you're right that in "some compilers/libraries" it does.  I would not rely on it.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PPj5M3) which compiles with gcc/clang. and MSVC is correct to reject code, as missing `#include <string>`.